# What's the inspiration for Once Upon a Time in Hollywood's name?

Tags: title, once-upon-a-time-in-hollywood

It is known that Quentin Tarantino and Robert Rodriguez have a special relationship. As is evident by [Tarantino's appearances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Dusk_till_Dawn) in Rodriguez' movies and by [Grindhouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grindhouse_(film)) - their co-directed double-feature.

Is the title of Once Upon a Time in Hollywood some kind of a reference or homage to Rodriguez' [Once Upon a Time in Mexico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time_in_Mexico)? Or is it just a fun way to capture the time-capsule feel of the movie, sending us back to another point in time? Or is it something else completely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both Tarantino and Rodriguez are paying homage to Sergio Leone, whose epics [*Once Upon a Time in the West* (1968)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064116/) and [*Once Upon a Time in America* (1984)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087843) are classics of the Western and gangster movie genres, respectively.

Before *Once Upon a Time...in Hollywood*, Tarantino had made nods towards Leone in several of his films, especially over the last 20 years.  The most obvious of these was the beginning title card of *Inglourious Basterds*, which reads "Once upon a time...in Nazi-occupied France."

Comment: Interesting! Do you have some citations or references about that connection?

Comment: This is well known.  Citations are not needed.